# InstantiationException is thrown

Tags: java, android, exception

I haven't finished this app, but I was hoping to see what it looks like on my phone. However, it force-closes with an InstantiationException.

Exception in logcat:

> 09-19 20:13:47.987: D/szipinf(5396): Initializing inflate state 09-19
>   20:13:48.007: D/dalvikvm(5396): newInstance failed: no () 09-19
>   20:13:48.007: D/AndroidRuntime(5396): Shutting down VM 09-19
>   20:13:48.007: W/dalvikvm(5396): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x4001d560) 09-19 20:13:48.017:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5396): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-19 20:13:48.017:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5396): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.hyperspacemg.showstopper/com.hyperspacemg.showstopper.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   com.hyperspacemg.showstopper.MainActivity 09-19 20:13:48.017:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5396):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
>   09-19 20:13:48.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
>   09-19 20:13:48.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123) 09-19
>   20:13:48.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
>   09-19 20:13:48.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-19
>   20:13:48.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 09-19 20:13:48.017:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5396):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835) 09-19
>   20:13:48.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-19
>   20:13:48.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 09-19 20:13:48.017:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5396):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
>   09-19 20:13:48.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622) 09-19
>   20:13:48.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-19 20:13:48.017:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5396): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   com.hyperspacemg.showstopper.MainActivity 09-19 20:13:48.017:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5396):   at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native
>   Method) 09-19 20:13:48.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):   at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409) 09-19 20:13:48.017:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5396):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
>   09-19 20:13:48.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
>   09-19 20:13:48.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5396):   ... 11 more 09-19
>   20:13:48.017: W/ActivityManager(1426):   Force finishing activity
>   com.hyperspacemg.showstopper/.MainActivity 09-19 20:13:48.177:
>   D/dalvikvm(1426): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 311K, 42% free 6658K/11335K,
>   external 2060K/2067K, paused 73ms 09-19 20:13:48.237:
>   D/dalvikvm(5379): GC_CONCURRENT freed 346K, 48% free 3158K/6023K,
>   external 0K/0K, paused 18ms+3ms 09-19 20:13:48.378: I/dalvikvm(5355):
>   Total arena pages for JIT: 11 09-19 20:13:48.518:
>   W/ActivityManager(1426): Activity pause timeout for
>   HistoryRecord{40824588 com.hyperspacemg.showstopper/.MainActivity}

**MainActivity**

```
package com.hyperspacemg.showstopper;

import com.hyperspacemg.showstopper.ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnColorChangedListener
    {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "ShowStopperPrefsFile";

    SeekBar seekbarChan, seekbarRed, seekbarGreen, seekbarBlue, seekbarBand, seekbarSens;
    TextView valueChan, valueRed, valueGreen, valueBlue, side, valueBand, valueSens, valueSave;
    private static int Chan = 0;
    private static int Rset = 0;
    private static int Gset = 0;
    private static int Bset = 0;
    private static int Side = 0;
    private static int Band = 0;
    private static int Sens = 24;
    private static int Save = 0;

    String chanFinal = null;
    String redFinal = null;
    String greenFinal = null;
    String blueFinal = null;
    String modeFinal = null;
    String sideFinal = null;
    String bandFinal = null;
    String sensFinal = null;
    String saveFinal = null;
    String message = "<HMG" + chanFinal + ":" + redFinal + ":" + greenFinal + ":" + blueFinal + ":" + modeFinal + ":" + sideFinal + ":" + bandFinal + ":" + sensFinal + ":" + saveFinal + ">"; 

    public MainActivity(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        valueChan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewChan);
        seekbarChan = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarChan);
        valueRed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRed);
        seekbarRed = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarRed);
        valueGreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewGreen);
        seekbarGreen = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarGreen);
        valueBlue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBlue);
        seekbarBlue = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarBlue);
        valueBand = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBand);
        seekbarBand = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarBand);
        valueSens = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSens);
        seekbarSens = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarSens);

        int sbar_chan_position = settings.getInt("seekbar_chan_pref", 0);
        seekbarChan.setProgress(sbar_chan_position);
        valueChan.setText("Channel: " + sbar_chan_position);
        Chan = sbar_chan_position;

        int sbar_red_position = settings.getInt("seekbar_red_pref", 0);
        seekbarRed.setProgress(sbar_red_position);
        valueRed.setText("Red: " + sbar_red_position);
        Rset = sbar_red_position;

        int sbar_green_position = settings.getInt("seekbar_green_pref", 0);
        seekbarGreen.setProgress(sbar_green_position);
        valueGreen.setText("Green: " + sbar_green_position);
        Gset = sbar_green_position;

        int sbar_blue_position = settings.getInt("seekbar_blue_pref", 0);
        seekbarBlue.setProgress(sbar_blue_position);
        valueBlue.setText("Blue: " + sbar_blue_position);
        Bset = sbar_blue_position;

        int sbar_band_position = settings.getInt("seekbar_band_pref", 0);
        seekbarBand.setProgress(sbar_band_position);
        valueBand.setText("Band: " + sbar_band_position);
        Band = sbar_band_position;

        int sbar_sens_position = settings.getInt("seekbar_sens_pref", 0);
        seekbarSens.setProgress(sbar_sens_position);
        valueSens.setText("Sensitivity: " + sbar_red_position);
        Sens = sbar_sens_position;

        seekbarChan.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                valueChan.setText("Channel: " + progress);

                Chan = progress;


                String chanFinal = "" + Chan;

            }
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

seekbarRed.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                valueRed.setText("Red: " + progress);

                Rset = progress;


                String redFinal = "" + Rset;

            }
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

seekbarGreen.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                valueGreen.setText("Green: " + progress);

                Gset = progress;


                String greenFinal = "" + Gset;

            }
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

seekbarBlue.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                valueBlue.setText("Blue: " + progress);

                Bset = progress;


                String blueFinal = "" + Bset;

            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

seekbarBand.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                    String audB = null;
                    switch(progress)
                    {
                    case 0:
                    audB = "63Hz";
                    break;
                    case 1:
                    audB = "160Hz";
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    audB = "400Hz";
                    break;
                    case 3:
                    audB = "1kHz";
                    break;
                    case 4:
                    audB = "2.5kHz";
                    break;
                    case 5:
                    audB = "6.25kHz";
                    break;
                    case 6:
                    audB = "16kHz";
                    break;
                    }
                valueBand.setText("Band: " + audB);

                Band = progress;


                String bandFinal = "" + Band;

            }
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

seekbarSens.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                    int sensitivity = progress + 1;
                valueSens.setText("Sensitivity: " + sensitivity);

                Sens = progress;


                String sensFinal = "" + Sens;

            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });










    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void colorChanged(int color) {

        int sbar_red_position = Color.red(color);
        int sbar_green_position = Color.green(color);
        int sbar_blue_position = Color.blue(color);

        seekbarRed.setProgress(sbar_red_position);
        valueRed.setText("Red: " + sbar_red_position);
        Rset = sbar_red_position;

        seekbarGreen.setProgress(sbar_green_position);
        valueGreen.setText("Green: " + sbar_green_position);
        Gset = sbar_green_position;

        seekbarBlue.setProgress(sbar_blue_position);
        valueBlue.setText("Blue: " + sbar_blue_position);
        Bset = sbar_blue_position;

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt("seekbar_red_pref", Rset);
        editor.putInt("seekbar_green_pref", Gset);
        editor.putInt("seekbar_blue_pref", Bset);
        editor.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onClickColorPicker(View v) {
        new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, Color.rgb(Rset, Gset, Bset)).show();
    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View v) {
        // When radio button is clicked

        // dumb stuff to make these radio group
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;

        RadioButton rb0 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);

        rb0.setChecked(false);
        rb1.setChecked(false);
        rb.setChecked(true);
        // end dumb stuff

        int checkedRadioButton = rb.getId();

        String radioButtonSelected = "";

        switch (checkedRadioButton) {
        case R.id.radio0:
            radioButtonSelected = "0";
            break;
        case R.id.radio1:
            radioButtonSelected = "1";
            break;
        }
        String audS = radioButtonSelected;
    }


}
```

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:padding="5dp">
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewChan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/channel"/>

 <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarChan"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewChan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="4"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChoose"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarChan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/choose"/>
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRandom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnChoose"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/random"/>
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRed"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnRandom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/Red" />
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarRed"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewRed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="255"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewGreen"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarRed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/Green" />
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarGreen"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewGreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="255"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewBlue"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarGreen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/Blue" />
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarBlue"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewBlue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="255"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerMode"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarBlue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/mode_array"
        android:prompt="@string/mode_prompt" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSide"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerMode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/side" />

      <RadioButton
          android:id="@+id/radio0"
          android:layout_below="@+id/textViewSide"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="left"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:checked="true"
          android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
          android:text="@string/left" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewSide"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/right" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewBand"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/band" />
        <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarBand"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewBand"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="5"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSens"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarBand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sens" />
        <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarSens"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewSens"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="255"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnApply"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarSens"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/apply"/>
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnApply"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/save"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Strings.xml**

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Show Stopper</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">Show Stopper</string>
    <string name="random">Random Color!</string>
    <string name="channel">Channel %d</string>
    <string name="Red">Red %d</string>
    <string name="Green">Green %d</string>
    <string name="Blue">Blue %d</string>
    <string name="side">Audio Side</string>
    <string name="left">Left</string>
    <string name="right">Right</string>
    <string name="band">Band %d</string>
    <string name="sens">Sensitivity %d</string>
    <string name="choose">Choose a Color!</string>
    <string name="apply">Apply</string>
    <string name="save">Save</string>

    <string name="mode_prompt">Choose a Mode</string>

    <string-array name="mode_array">
        <item>Random Fade</item>
        <item>HeartBeat Red</item>
        <item>Set Color</item>
        <item>Pulse Color</item>
        <item>Heartbeat Color</item>
        <item>Audio Color</item>
        <item>Audio Random Flash</item>
        <item>Audio Random Set</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: holy wall of code batman. why are you showing us your whole app, we aren't going to read and understand everything you have done so far with so little to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
public MainActivity(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

to:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: Yes, this allowed the app to display, so now, everything is blank (white) no controls, no app. Should I start a new question, or can you guys help me here?

Comment: You should start a new question. But first of all try to solve the problem yourself.